# Datetimepicker not calling/binding properly after removing dynamic input field

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, datepicker, datetimepicker

I am using jquery datetimepicker with the following version

```
JQuery v1.7.2
JQuery UI - v1.10.3
jQuery timepicker addon V1.3
```

In a module, I am creating input field dynamically by clicking **"+"** as well as binding the datetimepicker for those input which are created dynamically as well as removing that input field by clicking  **"-"**.

My dynamic input fields always create like below:

```
datepickerfrom_1_1
datepickerfrom_1_2
datepickerfrom_1_3
datepickerfrom_1_4
datepickerfrom_1_5
.
.
.
```

I am binding the datetimepicker by using jQuery like below:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('body').on('focus', 'input[id^="datepickerfrom"]', function() { // Id's Containing "datepickerfrom" string, bind the datetimepicker
        $(this).datetimepicker({
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            timeFormat: 'HH:mm:ss'
        });
    });
});
```

The `script(datetimepicker)` is working fine when dynamic input is created.

**Issue:**
I am adding some dynamic input field by clicking **"+"**, then I removed some of the inputs by clicking **"-"**, again I am adding some dynamic input fields. The second time created input field not calling/binding the datetimepicker properly.

What might be the issue? How can I solve it?

Comment: Try `Live` method in place of `on`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried it in jsfiddle and it worked, here is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/juTRR/

If you know your problem, reproduce it in jsfiddle so we can see what it is, because I don't see it. Maybe try to use `$(document).ready` instead of `$(window).load`, its the only thing I changed. Or maybe the problem is actually in your adding and removing functions, if so you should put them in your post.

Comment: The code is not working! how it should work.. As you see if we remove some textbox next time the id is increasing.. first text box is datefrom_1_1 second is datefrom_1_2 if I remove and ADD the ID is datefrom_1_3 not datefrom_1_2. I am changing the id again to datefrom_1_2 so it is not working.

Comment: I modified it so it works like you want, it still is working as usual. http://jsfiddle.net/ZCNMs/

Comment: thanks but when I use I am facing the same issue. Is it due to the JQuery Version?

Comment: What do you mean by "facing the same issue"? Are you talking about the jsfiddle? The jsfiddle should work the same for everybody, that's why we use it. No matter how much I remove or add in it the datetimepicker still opens when I click on the inputs. You can also see the Jquery version I used at the left, it's the same as yours.

Comment: I am using chrome too and it is working, I don't see why it's not working on your end, I didn't want to modify your code too much but if it is not working you can try this : http://jsfiddle.net/ztQYJ/


I modified the way to bind the datepickers, binding them one time at their creation instead of each time you click on them, maybe this will work better.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the jquery context in the 'on' function. In the function jquery.on you use $(this). $(this) will refer to you primary selector: $('body').

Have you tried:

```
$('input[id^="datepickerfrom"]').on('focus', function() {
```

[Examples](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) shows you need an input field. So I assume $('input[id^="datepickerfrom"]') is your input field.

Comment: The files are given in sthe same order JQuery v1.7.2,
JQuery UI - v1.10.3,
jQuery timepicker addon V1.3 and I added the CSS but still the same issue. I didnt added the Smooth.Js because if i include it other js are showing error.